# How to get a keys of nested json object in json heirarchy

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to javascript and json.Basically i have to fetch **all keys** of nested json object in a parent child relationship heirarchy.The keys are dynamic so I won't necessarily know the keys.
**for eg.** i have a json

```
 {
               "Indo-European": {
                   "Indo-Iranian": {
                       "Iranian": [
                           "Persian",
                           "Avestan",
                           "Sogdian",
                           "Baluchi",
                           "Kurdish",
                           "Pashto"
                       ],
                       "Indic": [
                           "Assamese",
                           "Bengali",
                           "Gujarati",
                           "Hindi",
                           "Marathi",
                           "Punjabi",
                           "Romany",
                           "Sindhi",
                           "Singhalese",
                           "Urdu"
                       ]
                   },
                      "Baltic": [
                           "Latvian",
                           "Lithuanian"
                   ]
                   }
           }
```

**output must be**-

```
Indo-European
    Indo-European.Indo-Iranian
        Indo-European.Indo-Iranian.Iranian
        Indo-European.Indo-Iranian.Indic
    Indo-European.Baltic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, runs in O(n3) time complexity but works

```js
let json = {
  "Indo-European": {
    "Indo-Iranian": {
      "Iranian": [
        "Persian",
        "Avestan",
        "Sogdian",
        "Baluchi",
        "Kurdish",
        "Pashto"
      ],
      "Indic": [
        "Assamese",
        "Bengali",
        "Gujarati",
        "Hindi",
        "Marathi",
        "Punjabi",
        "Romany",
        "Sindhi",
        "Singhalese",
        "Urdu"
      ]
    },
    "Baltic": [
      "Latvian",
      "Lithuanian"
    ]
  }
}

let lv1 = Object.keys(json)
lv1.forEach(i => {
  console.log(i)
  let lv2 = Object.keys(json[i])
  lv2.forEach(j => {
    console.log(`--${i}*${j}`)
    let lv3 = Object.keys(json[i][j])
    lv3.forEach(k => {
      if (!json[i][j].hasOwnProperty(length)) {
        console.log(`----${i}*${j}*${k}`)
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks,It works prefectly.But it would be great if it can be solved in less complixity